# cannot convert chinese characters to utf-8 format for the search functionality

Tags: cakephp, utf-8, cjk

i want to convert chinese characters to work for my search functions 
the database is in utf-8 format

on the page the chinese characters are displayed and they go in the query as they are
but the content in the database is in utf-8 format

Comment: I assume you are using `utf-8` encoding as your page charset as well? Do a `debug($this->data)` when you submit your search form and check that the characters are infact being `POSTed` as chinese. I had this problem but was using a windows machine and XAMPP which required additional configuration to play nice with utf8. When it went on the live server, everything worked perfectly ~

Answer (score 0):

Check that the database driver is not mangling the characters. e.g. the SQL Server driver mssql will not handle UTF-8 characters